# User permissions for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Please advice to give permission for a **SQL server** user. Conditions are, this user must be able to `create,delete,modify,drop` the `tables/view/procedure` on `user default schema(not dbo)` not in any other schema. I have given `db_ddladmin` privilege but here the user will be able to perform any action on other schema's as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA :: BobsSchema To Bob;
```

Where Bob is the users name. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here the user Bob will be able to edit/modify/alter the tables of other users as well. I have to restrict the permission to one schema.

Comment: @user2477113 - sorry, I initially read it as `dbo`, but you can switch it to name whatever other schema it is that you want them to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

If Bob is the owner of BobSchema then you don't need to set any permissions at all - object owners have full control over their objects.

Additionally, If Bob is the owner of BobSchema then Bob will by default be the owner of all objects created in BobSchema (in SQL Server 2005+).

So, one way to solve your situation is to create the schemas using something like `create schema BobSchema authorization Bob;`.